# Nginx .conf & simple math

Tags: nginx

Can you do simple math operations (add / subtract / division / multiplication) from within the nginx conf?

Comment: Write a perl/ruby/shell script to generate your nginx.conf file..?

Comment: If you really want to do math, the '[Embedded Perl](http://wiki.nginx.org/EmbeddedPerlModule)' module will let you include Perl code in your Nginx config. It does decrease performance a bit, but may be better than sending your files to PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope - but why would you need to?

There's probably a better way to do what you're looking to do without going through the hassle of turning your web server config into an Frankenstein combination of configuration and application logic - can you expand on your goal?

Comment: I have some obfuscated legacy ids that I'd like to just forward to the correct place. As they are images it seems wasteful to be sending all of them to PHP just to do some math.

Basically: http://blah.com/foobar.php?imageid=2300 --> /home/images/23.jpg . So it would be nice to just use an nginx alias to grab the right location rather than use the PHP.

Comment: Is it just a "grab the first two characters (or all but the last two) of the `imageid`", or is it more complex?  If it's string manipulation that can be accomplished by regex, then it's definitely doable.

Comment: some addition and division. btw, thanks for being so helpful :)

Comment: Unfortunately, no such luck then - doing the actual math is beyond the config file's capability.  Sounds like a job for PHP ;)

Answer (score 4):

nginx has two special modules, [embedded Perl](http://wiki.nginx.org/EmbeddedPerlModule) and Lua. Theres already two variation for Lua, [first](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule) and [second](https://github.com/alacner/nginx_lua_module) one.

If compiled with these, Perl scripts or Lua scripts can be inserted into the configuration files of nginx, so not only "simple" math but nearly anything Perl or Lua is able to do will be available inside nginx conf ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you build it with this module: https://github.com/arut/nginx-let-module/wiki