# How can I avoid users from downloading a big file?

Tags: nginx, http

I am serving a static folder with NGINX.

Inside that folder I have one particular file that is 60GB, but it is only meant to be read in small chunks, using an HTTP request like the following:

[image]

So if a user tries to download the entire file, NGINX should refuse it.

There are someways I see that this could be done, for eg.:

1. Check if the HTTP request header `Range` exists and the byte range is less than X.
2. Check if the requested response payload is less than, for eg., 100MB.

But I don't know how any of these can be implemented within NGINX.

Comment: What sort of file is it? A zip file or something else? A 60GB download doesn't sound like a great solution and it's possibly better off being rearchitected. Is this just downloaded using a web browser or some custom application? 

You could also look at storing that file on S3/Cloudfront and then you won't have to worry about people using up all of your bandwidth or choking your server

Comment: It is a BAM file. I have no choice, the user needs to access it (with byte range), that I cannot change, that's simply how you navigate in genomic files. I just want to avoid the user to be able to download the whole file, while still allowing the user to access parts of the file.

Comment: CGI is a bit old-school but it seems like a simple CGI script in your language of choice would work well here. If you must do it in the nginx config I thing you are going to need to add an [additional module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-let-module/wiki) since by default [you can't do math in the nginx config](https://serverfault.com/questions/360240).

Comment: @PedroD, What are the headers if the user attempts to grab the entire 60GB file? Might have a solution for you.

Comment: They wont have the `Range` header present in the HTTP request, or they might have the `Range` in the header, but with a very long byte range covering the whole file

Comment: You can extend Nginx with a scripting language "njs",see https://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/index.html ; the code executed there has full access to the incoming request and hence could decide to honour it or not based on `range` header. You can use Perl as a language too. Other option: install the WAF dynamic module which gives you modsecurity which one can be configured to look at headers and filter the request too. https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/updated-mitigation-of-apache-range-header-dos-attack/ is loosely related but shows the complexity of the `range` header

Comment: "I just want to avoid the user to be able to download the whole file" For which reasons? Performance? Or confidentiality? In the last case nothing will prohibit user to do multiple queries with different range and reconstruct the file locally...

Comment: I forgot: of course you can script Nginx with lua code, so again a piece of code will get all the incoming HTTP headers and can decide what to do based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, that You can configure nginx to check specific location (60gb file location) for specific (Range) header existence. Then You could block requests that don't contain Range header.

You could check these links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970620/nginx-reject-request-if-header-is-not-present-or-wrong

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342049/nginx-reject-request-if-header-not-present/35366796

**Edit**

It seems a bit problematic coding complex conditions in `Nginx` configuration.
Maybe You should consider serving large file using some server-side scripting, ie. PHP. There are plenty of examples of streaming scripts.

https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293

After configuring Nginx to using such a script, You need to add logic to script (Range conditions) and also prevent direct access to large file.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is covered in the Slice module here - https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/slice/

Comment: My problem is not achieving this slicing feature, HTTP already provides that with the "Range" header. My issue here is that I want to force the client to always use that header when requesting a specific file. Or maybe, alternatively, get NGINX to kill any connection/session that takes more than X seconds to terminate (in order to avoid the download of big files, which would take much more than X seconds).